# Count concurrent subscriptions

Tags: stata, panel-data

I have a database with a number of people who (may) have multiple subscriptions to a service running at once and transactional data for each event during the life of their subscription. I am trying to create a variable that counts the number of current active subscriptions the user has at a given transaction time.

To illustrate an example, my data lives in the form:

```
person | subscription | obs_date | sub_start_date | sub_end_date | num_concurrent_subs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 1            | 09/01/10 | 09/01/10       | 09/01/11     | 1
1      | 1            | 10/01/10 | 09/01/10       | 09/01/11     | 2
1      | 1            | 11/01/10 | 09/01/10       | 09/01/11     | 2
1      | 2            | 10/01/10 | 10/01/10       | 09/01/11     | 2
1      | 2            | 11/01/10 | 10/01/10       | 09/01/11     | 2
1      | 3            | 11/01/14 | 09/01/14       | .            | 1
1      | 3            | 11/01/16 | 09/01/14       | .            | 1
1      | 4            | 11/01/15 | 10/01/15       | 11/01/15     | 3
1      | 5            | 11/01/15 | 10/01/15       | 11/01/15     | 3
```

And so on and so forth for each person. I want to generate the `num_concurrent_subs` as above.

That is, for each person, look at each observation and find how many subscriptions it falls into the range `sub_start_date` to `sub_end_date`.

I've read a bit on Stata's `count` function and believe I'm close to a solution, but I'm not sure how to check it across different subscriptions.

Comment: Strictly `count` is a command, not a function. In Stata commands and functions are different kinds of beasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by separating the subscription information from the transaction data and convert the subscription data to long form, with one observation for the start date and another for the end date. Then you recombine with the transaction data and order by a single date variable. You use an `onoff` variable to track the start and end of each subscription. Something like:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte(person subscription) str8(obs_date sub_start_date sub_end_date) byte num_concurrent_subs
1 1 "09/01/10" "09/01/10" "09/01/11" 1
1 1 "10/01/10" "09/01/10" "09/01/11" 2
1 1 "11/01/10" "09/01/10" "09/01/11" 2
1 2 "10/01/10" "10/01/10" "09/01/11" 2
1 2 "11/01/10" "10/01/10" "09/01/11" 2
1 3 "11/01/14" "09/01/14" "."        1
1 3 "11/01/16" "09/01/14" "."        1
1 4 "11/01/15" "10/01/15" "11/01/15" 3
1 5 "11/01/15" "10/01/15" "11/01/15" 3
end

* should always have an observation identifier
gen obsid = _n

* convert string to Stata numeric dates
gen odate = daily(obs_date,"MD20Y")
gen substart = daily(sub_start_date,"MD20Y")
gen subend = daily(sub_end_date,"MD20Y")
format %td odate substart subend
save "main_data.dta", replace

* reduce to subscription info with one obs for the start and one obs
* for the end of each subscription. use an onoff variable to tract
* start and end events
keep person subscription substart subend
bysort person subscription substart subend: keep if _n == 1
expand 2
bysort person subscription: gen adate = cond(_n == 1, substart, subend)
by person subscription: gen onoff = cond(_n == 1, 1, -1)
replace onoff = 0 if mi(adate)
format %td adate

append using "main_data.dta"

* include obs date in adate and nothing happens on the observation date
replace adate = odate if !mi(obsid)
replace onoff = 0 if !mi(obsid)

* order by person adate, put on event first, then obs events, then off events
gsort person adate -onoff
by person: gen concur = sum(onoff)

* return to original obs
keep if !mi(obsid)
sort obsid
```

Comment: Discussion of the `expand 2` trick at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0068

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do this using `rangejoin` (from SSC). To install it, type in Stata's Command window:

```
ssc install rangejoin
```

With `rangejoin`, you can pair each subscription with all transactional data that falls within the subscription start and end date. Then, it's just a matter of counting, per transaction observation, how many subscription is it paired with.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte(person subscription) str8(obs_date sub_start_date sub_end_date) byte num_concurrent_subs
1 1 "09/01/10" "09/01/10" "09/01/11" 1
1 1 "10/01/10" "09/01/10" "09/01/11" 2
1 1 "11/01/10" "09/01/10" "09/01/11" 2
1 2 "10/01/10" "10/01/10" "09/01/11" 2
1 2 "11/01/10" "10/01/10" "09/01/11" 2
1 3 "11/01/14" "09/01/14" "."        1
1 3 "11/01/16" "09/01/14" "."        1
1 4 "11/01/15" "10/01/15" "11/01/15" 3
1 5 "11/01/15" "10/01/15" "11/01/15" 3
end

* should always have an observation identifier
gen obsid = _n

* convert string to Stata numeric dates
gen odate = daily(obs_date,"MD20Y")
gen substart = daily(sub_start_date,"MD20Y")
gen subend = daily(sub_end_date,"MD20Y")
format %td odate substart subend
save "main_data.dta", replace

* reduce to subscription start and end date per person
bysort person subscription substart subend: keep if _n == 1
keep person substart subend

* missing values will exclude obs so use a date in the future
replace subend = mdy(1,1,2099) if mi(subend)

* pair each subscription with an obs date
rangejoin odate substart subend using "main_data.dta", by(person)

* the number of current subcription is the number of pairings
bysort obsid: gen current = _N

* return to original obs
by obsid: keep if _n == 1
sort obsid
drop substart subend
rename (substart_U subend_U) (substart subend)
```